# how to get audio/video files stored in aws s3 with springboot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, amazon-s3, audio

I made a library of folders which include audio/video files on s3 storage.
I want to stream music/video files from aws s3 storage.
I know how to get bucket list only and list of objects present in those buckets.
Is there any method to stream/download those files through springboot?
I am using aws sdk v2.

I tried getting an object but this is not happening the way I wanted.
please tell me what I am doing wrong? I am new to development world 
I thought it would show some json response at least:

```java
public GetObjectResponse getObject(String bucket) {

    // even tried by hardcoding the key value
    String key="WhatsApp Audio 2019-08-31 at 2.32.03 AM.mpeg";
    GetObjectResponse response=client.getObject(GetObjectRequest.builder().bucket(bucket).key(key).build(),
                ResponseTransformer.toFile(Paths.get("multiPartKey")));
    return response;    
}
```

Comment: Working on a demo for this use case.

Answer (score 3):

It all depends on the context of what you are trying to achieve. If it is a service that should serve streaming media requests and be scalable and available - then it is rather a serious architecture design problem than just a Spring Boot method. Even if it's just a sandbox experimental project, you still need to be more specific on **what's the type of the app that you are building** (web app with rest API, a unix service process, just an executable program or anything else) and **who is the client** (where do you stream).

Moreover, video streaming and audio streaming - those are 2 different worlds (different codecs, http headers and other nuances).

[Here](https://melgenek.github.io/spring-video-service) is a pretty good observation on how to build a video streaming web-service with Spring Boot. Also, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49810299/5071635) discussion suggests using [Spring Content](https://paulcwarren.github.io/spring-content/). I took shots in the dark. Do your own research based on what exactly you need.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an AWS tutorial that shows you how to build a Spring Boot web application that reads and streams Amazon Simple Storage Service (Amazon S3) video content over HTTP. In this use case, the menu that appears in the view is built by reading object tags.

[image]

https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/master/javav2/usecases/create_spring_stream_app